# Template specialization static initialization icc+vc vs gcc+clang

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

It looks like compilers accept different syntax to initialization of static in template.

```
template <typename T> struct TBase
{   
    static const int i;
    static const int j;
};

// compile: gcc + clang + visual + icc
template <> const int TBase<double>::i=1;

// compile: vc + icc
// failed gcc, gcc -fpermissive, clang
const int TBase<double>::j=2;
```

Is the syntax without `template<>` accepted by the standard even if it's obviously not portable at the moment ?

edit: 
With this code on vc++  `TBase<double>::i==1` and `TBase<double>::j==2` exactly like the code without template.

```
struct noTemplate 
{   
    static const int i;
    static const int j;
};
const int noTemplate::i=1; 
const int noTemplate::j=2;
```

gcc and clang seems to enforce the use of `template<>` to initialize this static, I don't see why compiler need this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two syntaxes are both valid, but they mean different things. The syntax with `template<>` is used to declare or define a member of an implicit or explicit *instantiation*:

```
template<class T> struct X { static int const i; };

template<> int const X<char>::i = 1; // Define member of an implicit instantiation

template struct X<long>;
template<> int const X<long>::i = 2; // Define member of an explicit instantiation
```

The syntax without `template<>` is used to define a member of a *specialization*:

```
template<> struct X<float> { static int const j; }; // Class template specialization
int const X<float>::j = 3;
```

Comment: Thanks. So implicit instantiation is for template local usage, explicit instantiation for template export like in lib. With vc++ the template declaration and initialisation of a value like int const X<mytype>::j = 3; is enough for code (x<Mytype>()).j to be "valid" seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems to meet standard.

At least C++14 standard contains (hope its final revision contains it as well, I've checked with pre-release version http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf).

> 14.7.1 Implicit instantiation
>   ...
>   Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.
>   ...

By `const int TBase<double>::j=0;` you are accessing (not specializing) static member `j` of `TBase<double>`, so `TBase<double>` specialization should be created if not existed yet.

The code sample without templates, which proves that you are just accessing struct member:

```
struct WithoutTemplate {
    static const int i;
};
const int WithoutTemplate::i = 5;
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question to emphasize my interrogations.